# Animate UIBarButtonItem like Notes app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I just wanted to know how I could copy the trash animation of the Notes.app application. I presume this would include two images and the class of the button is `UIBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is either replace the image with an animated image or if it's already an image stack, play the animation.

**Switching:**

- When the button is released change
  the Image of the Button to an
  "animated" Image (array) and play the
  image stack.
- Once the animation `didFinishPlaying`
  (I think) replace the Button Image
  with the original static/single
  Image.

*(This is much the same way you would easily do it in CSS/HTML.)*

**Animating:**

- When the button is release play the
  current image stack
- When the animation finishes it's
  done.

*(Basically when there is only one action: `play` (on release).)*

Now, if you want to do the complete animation cycle of the button and the view it becomes a bit trickier, but not too hard.

**The Kitchen Sink:**

- You need to have the complete image
  stack of the trash in it's closed
  state, opening animation sequence and
  closing animation sequence.
- The releasing on the icon, you start
  the first half of the animation
  sequences (opening animation).
- At the end of the sequence (or in
  parallel) you animate a transition on
  the view your "deleting" such as
  warping the view so it scales into
  the trash.
- When this animation finishes you send
  the callback/notification/message to
  the button saying I'm done (play
  closing animation)
- Then rest at the initial frame of the
  image stack (closed state).

I don't have the code written for you but I could write pseudo code if you'd like...

Cheers and good luck! (^_^)

Comment: Great, detailed answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean `pseudo code` -- sudo-code doesn't make sense here (sudo == superuser do)

Answer (score -1):

In your UINavigationController, this is how you do it:

```
UIBarButtonItem *clearAll = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(trashMethod)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = clearAll;
```

Comment: thanks, but I using that code currently. What my question was is how can I animate it to look the same?